# Multi language GUI - internationalization

Tags: qt, internationalization

I'm working on a project which will be used in many countries, with different languages. I need a good way to make my GUI easy to translate.

I'm programming using the Qt framework.

Obviously I'll have to define all of the String's in a sort of lookup table / .ini file. I'm just not sure what the best way to do this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt supports Internationalization (i18n) quite well, and they even have a pretty thorough [documentation page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html) explaining some of the techniques that you can use.

For translation, the biggest thing will be to use `tr("...")` when inserting strings, and then using [`Qt Linguist`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-manual.html) to actually translate those strings.